# Read multiple texts Qt

Tags: qt

i am doing Qt project about displaying many texts. in detail, after 1st text display, it will close then display next file. My problem here was that just the last file displayed. all link resource paths are correct. Please help me fix me. Thanks in advance

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QString>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QStringList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStringList L;
    L << ":/sample.txt" << ":/idp.txt";

    foreach (QString str, L){
        QFile file(str);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            QMessageBox::information(0,"error file path", file.errorString());

        QString name = file.fileName();
        QStringList parts = name.split("/");
        QString lastBit = parts.at(parts.size()-1);
        statusBar()->showMessage(lastBit);

        QTextStream out(&file);
        QString txt = out.readAll();
        QStackedWidget  *temp = new QStackedWidget();
        QTextBrowser *textbrs = new QTextBrowser();
        textbrs->setText(txt);
        temp->addWidget(textbrs);
        setCentralWidget(temp);
        file.close();
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: In each iteration, you're replacing the stacked widget with a new one, discarding the previous one.

Comment: Move your ReadAndDisplay Code to a slot in MainWindow and use a QTimer to load and display the next file every second. Or switch on Button/Key. As it is right now your just keep loading and displaying while nothing has been shown yet (ui will be updated AFTER constructor).

Comment: @SebastianLange, i already use QTimer like timer->start(5000);
        connect (timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(file));  // but it doesnt work. i connect the SLOT to file.close() function. I want 1st file display, then after 5s, it close and load 2nd file and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QString>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QStringList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);                                 
    L << ":/sample.txt" << ":/idp.txt";    //Class member of Type QStringList
    textbrs = new QTextBrowser();          //Class member of Type QTextBrowser*
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(textbrs);
    timer = new QTimer();                  //Class member of Type QTimer*
    timer->setInterval(5000);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(slotFileAction()));
    timer->start();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slotFileAction()
{
   static int count = 0;
   if(count >= L.size())
       timer->stop();
   QString str = L.at(count);
   count++;
   QFile file(str);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        QMessageBox::information(0,"error file path", file.errorString());

    QString name = file.fileName();
    QStringList parts = name.split("/");
    QString lastBit = parts.at(parts.size()-1);
    statusBar()->showMessage(lastBit);

    QTextStream out(&file);
    QString txt = out.readAll();

    textbrs->setText(txt);        
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it solve the QTimer problem. But it display black window. I fixed with delete ui->central.... then replace by temp = new QStackedWidget(); And in slotFileAction(), i keep my old code QTextStream out(&file);
        QString txt = out.readAll();

        textbrs->setText(txt);
        temp->addWidget(textbrs);
        setCentralWidget(temp);  // it works well. Anw, thank you so much

Comment: A stacked Widget is for holding multiple widgets on different Indexes, so you could switch between them. IF you just want to have a "single" widget and replace this one, just use QWidget. You could use QStackedWidget::addWidget() so you can go back using QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex(index);

Answer (score 0):

Each time you will replace the old QStackedWidget by
`setCentralWidget(temp);`
The example to use QStackedWidget in Qt help document is following:

```
QWidget *firstPageWidget = new QWidget;
QWidget *secondPageWidget = new QWidget;
QWidget *thirdPageWidget = new QWidget;

QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
stackedWidget->addWidget(firstPageWidget);
stackedWidget->addWidget(secondPageWidget);
stackedWidget->addWidget(thirdPageWidget);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(stackedWidget);
setLayout(layout);
```

So, you should add multiple QTextBrowsers in QStackedWidget by `addWidget()` and use `setCentralWiget()` just once.

Hope helpful.

Comment: thanks. i did it but not load the text file. my aim is just 1 text load, next file will load when the 1st close.